# Example of a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ where $(\lim\sup x_n)^2\neq \lim \sup (x_n^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

My question is exactly as the title states. I'm struggling to come up with an example of a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ where $(\lim\sup x_n)^2\neq \lim \sup (x_n^2)$. Anyone have any simple examples? Thanks in advance.

Does this work?
$(x_n)=(-1,-2,-1,-2,...)$.
Then $(\lim\sup x_n)^2=(-1)^2=1$ but $(x_n)^2=(1,4,1,4,...)$ so $\lim \sup (x_n^2)=4$

Comment: Find how to ask here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/

Comment: Are you sure it exists?

Comment: Do you know two numbers $a < b$ but $a^2 > b^2$?

Comment: The sequence you gave works.

Comment: You can think of a sequence that jumps between 0 and -1, so it's limit of suprema is 0, while the squares has limit of suprema 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this work?
> $(x_n)=(-1,-2,-1,-2,...)$.
> Then $(\lim\sup x_n)^2=(-1)^2=1$ but $(x_n)^2=(1,4,1,4,...)$ so $\lim \sup (x_n^2)=4$

Yes, that works perfectly well, and is essentially what I was hinting at with my comment.  As an extension, try to show
$$\limsup (x_n^2) = \max\left((\limsup(x_n))^2,(\liminf(x_n))^2\right)$$
(You can also try to find a formula for $\liminf(x_n^2)$ but it's a little more difficult to write out)